# Smooth scroll script blocking links

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the following script to smooth scroll to anchor points on my web page. The problem I am having is that I have a couple href links to different pages but this seems to be blocking them from opening. Can only open them by right clicking 'open new tab'.

Any help much appreciated. Thanks.

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(event){
event.preventDefault();

$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
}, 500);
});
```

Comment: `event.preventDefault()` prevents the default behavior of an anchor element e.g. redirecting to the link.

Comment: @TimVermaelen removed this and it has worked as I wanted. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix this by removing event.preventDefault()